# gnuplot move data point on x axis

Tags: gnuplot

i am plotting the attached graph using following script and data set:

```
set term postscript enhanced color solid
set output "speedup_v1.ps" 
set title "Speedup"
set key left top
set yrange[0:128]
set xtics (0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128)
set xlabel 'Processes'
set ylabel 'Speedup'
plot 'speedup_v1.dat' using 1:2 title "Speedup" with linespoints, \
     'speedup_v1.dat' using 1:3 title "Speedup (linear)" with linespoints

0    0     0
1    1     1
2    1,692 2
4    3,675 4
8    7,739 8
16   9,840 16
32   18,61 32
64   42,77 64
128  82,43 128
```

I would like to remain the graph like it is right now but the data points on the x axis should have the same distance between each other. Right now `64p -> 128p` eats up half of the screen, i want it to be `1/8`. Thanks in advance!

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to remain the graph like it is right now but the data points on the x axis should have the same distance between each other.

The "look" of a graph depends on the way the axis are formated. If you want the x-axis to be spread evenly, then the look of the graph will differ.

I suppose you are looking for a logscale?
Try issuing the command

```
set logscale x
```

and see how the values will equally spread over the x-axis.
Please note, that the logscale will only work in your case, since your data is spread logarithmically.

I hope this is what you were looking for

cherio Woltan

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at things like

```
set size square
```

that makes the plot square (predictably enough),

The set size command is particularly useful if you want to make the text bigger (in your graph it is a bit small).

You can do things like

```
set size 0.5, 0.5
```

and this reduces the size of the graph by half, but not the size of the text.